# Installing ubuntu 18.04 on asus rog strix G15CX: how to disable RST so linux can see nvme drives

Tags: asus, rst

I have a new asus rog strix G15CX desktop computer.  I have successfully installed ubuntu 18.04 on the included sata 2TB spinning disk but cannot use the nvme drives (which are fine according to windows installed on 500G windows system drive; 2nd drive is Samsung 1TB nvme).

Since it's a new machine, I haven't populated with my data/programs, just installing/configuring it now.  Windows is happy on a raid-attached nvme; linux can't see nvme drives **except for syslog**.

Syslog has the following info:

```
Dec 26 15:06:01 kernel: [    1.206643] ahci 0000:00:17.0: version 3.0
Dec 26 15:06:01 kernel: [    1.206760] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Found 2 remapped NVMe devices.
Dec 26 15:06:01 kernel: [    1.206761] ahci 0000:00:17.0: Switch your BIOS from RAID to AHCI mode to use them.
```

I can't find a way to do this in the BIOS (American Megatrends 303).

Am I out of luck here, or is there a way for linux to use these drives??

Thanks,

M.

Comment: What OS & release are you asking about?

Comment: Hi leonkato! Can you see your nvme drive in Gnome Disks? To check press the "super key" on your keyboard (also known as the "Windows key") type "disks" - the app should show up.
Also, is this a dual boot environment and do you have backups? (Just to be safe.)

Comment: Disks only shows the spinning disk that has 18.04 and nothing else.

Comment: lsb_release shows Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell the only option you currently have is switching the SATA mode to AHCI in your computer's BIOS. [There](https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/6/20/27) seems to have been work in 2019 trying to add support for remapped NVME drives to the kernel, but it doesn't seem to have been accepted/released. There's also an Ubuntu bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1808842).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way (I've looked exhaustively) to do the switch in the BIOS.  So Linux lives on  slow spinning disk while 2 perfectly good nvme drives sit idle.  Seems like my only option is to trash the motherboard and acquire one that supports AHCI.

Comment: It's a real shame since the machine is very nice for Windows.  And thanks for the super well informed answer.

Comment: You're welcome, leonkato! True, it's a real shame... If this specific hardware setup stays around it's *probably* going to get integrated into the kernel at some point - but that doesn't help you now. :(